# Google Chrome Extension weird rendering

Tags: google-chrome-extension, rendering

I was playing around with some Chrome Extensions, testing stuff, changing samples, etc, when randomly my Google Chrome started to render popup windows that way:

[image: Weird rendering of every Google Chrome Extension with a popup]

Why? Can anyone help me, please?

[Update]

I don't know why but everything is normal now and I really didn't do anything to fix it.

Comment: Post your code if you actually want help

Comment: Uninstall/unload the extensions.

Comment: The extension on that image is from a sample found here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html

Comment: I already tried to uninstall and unload

Comment: and reload the extension

Comment: But it happens with every extension that has a popup not only this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but everything is normal now and I really didn't do anything to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the length of the scrollbar, and with that tab open on HackerNews, I'd say renderer mess-ups come in the area of conceivable scenarios. :P

Anyway. If you're not running Chrome from a dev channel, and you're positive you're with the latest stable version you can do this:

1. Disable all other extensions and enable them back, one-by-one; one of them might have GL-related features that don't play well with your video card drivers
2. Search your extension folder for `.dll` files, who knows which one might try to do what
3. Run Chrome as Administrator; look out for any other software that you might have installed. They can intercept and reposition windows around the screen but in Administrator mode they might just be inhibited
4. Finally, disable your video card driver from `devmgmt.msc` (not recommended, just for debugging purposes)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already did that... But it's working now and I have no idea what caused that strange behavior =p